# Is it possible to use compile time variables in coffeescript?

Tags: compilation, coffeescript, environment-variables

An example of what I would like to achieve:

```
SERVER=localhost:3000 coffee -o src/ coffee/
```

sample.coffee

```
$.post "ENV.SERVER", data
```

sample.js

```
$.post("localhost:3000", data);
```

Notes and ideas are welcome, though I could do it like this:

```
source.replace("ENV.SERVER","localhost:3000");
```

Comment: What is the execution environment? Browser or Server (Node.js)

Comment: I'm precompiling the code on a linux machine using the `coffee` command line tool